# How to do Angular *ngFor on bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to use bootstrap 4 carousel as a content slider for angular 5 .

I want to do an *ngFor and for the active carousel item, show 4 *ngFor results.

This is what I've so far.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="row mar-30">
          <div  class=" col-md-3" 
          *ngFor="let blog of blogs | async; let i = index"
          >
          <div *ngIf="i<4">
              <app-blogcard
              (checked)="OnChecked($event)"
              [blog]="blog"
              ></app-blogcard>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

This will show just four items for the active carousel item because I did an *ngIf limit of 4. Is there anyway I can do this better without having to do another *ngFor on the next carousel item?

Answer (score 0):

use `slice` in your `*ngFor`

```
 <div  class=" col-md-3" 
          *ngFor="let blog of (blogs ? blogs.slice(0,4): []) | async; let i = index"
          >
          <div >
              <app-blogcard
              (checked)="OnChecked($event)"
              [blog]="blog"
              ></app-blogcard>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get your issue, but I "perfected" your code. Feel free to take a look :

```
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let blog of blogs?.slice(0, 4) | async; let i = index">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{i}}"></li>
    </ng-container>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="row mar-30">
        <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let blog of blogs?.slice(0, 4)">
          <app-blogcard (checked)="OnChecked($event)" [blog]="blog"></app-blogcard>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks even though u didn't quite get the code! I am getting this error though ```core.js:1427 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'slide-to' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. (".slice(0, 4) | async; let i = index">
```

Comment: Well could you explain it briefly to me ? What is your issue for instance ? And this error comes from an Input, I don't think what I did is actually the issue ... Are you sure you used `data-slide-to="{{i}}"` and not `[data-slide-to]="i"` ?

Comment: I am trying to use bootstrap 4 as a content slider. On each carousel item, I want to show 4 ngFor results...and next 4 items and so on as the slider works. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does now ! But you won't achieve that with only Javascript. You need to nest 2 loops inside each other, one that will create your carousel items, and another (the nested one) that will create your components. You can't use conditions here, you should instead use getter and setters !

Comment: Thanks. Am using Angular. It's just JavaScript.

Comment: Frick me, I meant HTML. You need to use Javascript to do that, not just HTML :)

Comment: haha. Any code sample? I am struggling with this at the moment!

Comment: Sorry no, I've never done that before ... But if I were to, I would either use getters to return corresponding arrays, or modulos with divisions